# Springmvc interceptors makes CORS annaotion and interceptors fail to handle Cross-domain

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, vue.js, cors

I have a custom interceptor in my project and I put a @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600) on my Controller .

When I ***don't*** use the  custom interceptor, ***the @CrossOrigin works***,

but when I ***use*** my custom interceptor, ***@CrossOrign doesn't work***!

And I also try to use my ***custom CorsInterceptor*** to handle the problem, however, 
 it ***doesn't work*** too

How should I solve the  Cross-domain problem ?

This is my custom CorsInterceptor:

```
public class ProcessInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            "POST, GET, OPTIONS,PUT, HEAD, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

    return true;

}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

This is my mvc configuration:

```
<mvc:interceptors>

    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <bean class="com.dorm.interceptor.ProcessInterceptor"></bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/static/css/**" />
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/user/login" />
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/student/login" />
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/static/fonts/**" />
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/static/js/**" />
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/static/img/**" />
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/user/testsession" />
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/swagger-ui.html" />
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/swagger-resources/**" />
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/webjars/**" />
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/v2/**" />
        <bean class="com.dorm.interceptor.LoginAndPermInter"></bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>

</mvc:interceptors>
```

The @CrossOrgin on Controller

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
    public class UserLoginController {//...}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use mvc XML namespace, I recommend you use mvc:cors namespace.
I'm not sure that it's an exact solution, but I was successful.

-- mvc XML Namespace --

```
<!-- CORS -->
<mvc:cors>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**" allowed-origins="*"/>
</mvc:cors>
```

According CORS support in Spring Framework, CORS requests include preflight ones with an OPTIONS method. It means that OPTIONS method should be requested before some requests like GET or POST. So, if you try to deal with an authorization by interceptor, you might add some actions for OPTIONS method on preHandle. Actually, It depends on browser. IE doesn't matter but, it's necessary for Chrome and Firefox.

https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

-- Interceptor Bean --

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {

    if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
        // return true or Some actions to avoid CORS; 
    } 
}
```